# Higher-dimensional analogues of the equivalence of compact Riemann surfaces and projective curves

Tags: soft-question

I'm going to be studying this result for a dissertation this year, and I wondered what there were in the way of higher-dimensional analogues? Also, what are some standing research questions on this theme? I think the interplay of the different theories is fascinating.